# MySQL: Self-referential not null, auto_increment, foreign key?

Tags: mysql

Is it possible in MySQL (in any version) to declare and use a table with a self-referential, not null, foreign key column referring to the AUTO_INCREMENT primary key of the same table?

Essentially, I'd like to create the following table, the rows of which represent a forest of trees.  I'd like the root nodes in the hierarchy to be indicated by the `parent_id` of the row being equal to the `id` (rather than allowing NULL in `parent_id` to indicate the root).

e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE forest (
    id BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    parent_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT fk_forest_parent_id FOREIGN KEY(parent_id) REFERENCES forest(id),
    name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
```

Creating this table works (5.0.44sp1-enterprise-gpl-nt-log MySQL Enterprise Server (GPL)).  However it does not appear to be possible to use LAST_INSERT_ID() to insert the `parent_id` of root nodes (which is not much of a surprise).  The following doesn't work for example :

```
INSERT INTO forest(parent_id, name) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), "root 1");
```

The following does work, but is no longer making use of the auto increment:

```
INSERT INTO forest(id, parent_id, name) VALUES (1234, 1234, "root 1");
```

Is there a way to use a table defined in this way whilst still relying on the automatically generated PK, and whilst also retaining all of the constraints (NOT NULL, and FOREIGN KEY)?

UPDATE - POSSIBLE SOLUTIONS:

```
START TRANSACTION;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
INSERT INTO forest(parent_id, name) VALUES (0, "root X");
UPDATE forest SET parent_id = LAST_INSERT_ID() WHERE id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1; /* This seems to be important. */
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Leave the parent nullable. If you want it to be the same value as the id the you can add a calculated column `seriously_this_parent_id As Coalesce(parent_id, id)`

Comment: There's nothing wrong in such kind of keys. But using `LAST_INSERT_ID()` in the same statement where the ID is going to be generated will obviously not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's impossible to know what the `id` of a row is going to be before the `INSERT` completes, so calling `LAST_INSERT_ID()` when no `INSERT` has been done does not do anything.  Instead you would need two separate statements (which could be run as a transaction in a stored procedure or what have you).

```
INSERT INTO forest(name) VALUES ("root 1");
UPDATE forest SET parent_id = LAST_INSERT_ID() WHERE id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

I don't think it makes sense for a root node to reference itself as a parent, though.  Just saying.

Comment: Tried that (inside a START TRANSACTION ... COMMIT).  Fails with `Error: Field 'parent_id' doesn't have a default value`.

Comment: @Paul I didn't think about that.  You can either make the `parent_id` nullable (which you probably want to avoid) or set it to `0`

Comment: BTW.  It seemed reasonable to me to use 'PK == FK implies root' both because nearly all the nodes *do* have a parent (hence NOT NULL) and - in particular - because the the root nodes are actually going to be pre-created and permanently owned by a parent type (different table).  [This is all happening underneath a Java data access layer I'm working on.]

Comment: Can't set `parent_id` to 0 - its a foreign key.  `Error: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (forest, CONSTRAINT fk_forest_parent_id FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES forest(id))`

Comment: @Paul that means that you need to have some kind of a genesis node that does have an `id` of `0`, or you can do `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0` for the transaction

Comment: Interesting.  I didn't know you could do that.  (Though, it appears, the FK constraint isn't applied *even on COMMIT* - i.e. I now have data in my example DB that violates the constraints of my database!)

Comment: Also, by 'genesis node' I'm guessing you mean some sort of 'root of the universe' node which all the other (root) nodes have as their 'parent'.  (But then that node would have to have a `parent_id` - given the constraints above - so I'm not sure that gets use anywhere.)

Comment: @Paul why would you COMMIT before setting the `parent_id` correctly?

Comment: I didn't - I committed afterwards.  It seems to be necessary to explicitly `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1` before the end of the TX; otherwise it appears to *stay* off, at least for that Connection (I kind of assumed it wouldn't).

Comment: @Paul it will stay off for the connection.  Sorry for not making that clear.  However it is just per-connection (i.e. it doesn't disable them altogether)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42058/discussion-between-paul-and-explosion-pills)